# Deploy Web Service with a different URL

Tags: java, wsdl, glassfish, jax-ws

I try to deploy a Web-service on Glassfish. Everything works fine. The web-service use a  befor defined WSDL File i do this with Annotation:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "Daten", portName = "DatenSOAP", wsdlLocation = "Daten.wsdl",
    targetNamespace = "http://foo.blub.com/ws/test/Service",
    endpointInterface = "com.blub.foo.ws.test.service.Daten")
```

and in my WSDL File i Define

```
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/servlet/test/Daten" />
```

But when i deploy this the WSDL is deployed on `http://localhost:8080/foo/Daten`

What is wrong where can i define the location?

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered, JAX-WS by default will use the context root and the service name as the published endpoint location.  Your project is deployed with a context root of 'foo' and the 'Daten' comes from the serviceName attribute of the @WebService annotation.
This is actually quite convenient and I would recommend you stick with the default unless you have a firm requirement to do otherwise.

If you do have such a requirement, the process for customizing the endpoint using web.xml servlet mapping is described here ([http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.wsfep.multiplatform.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Ftwbs_customwebxml.html](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.wsfep.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/twbs_customwebxml.html))

Hopefully that helps.